# How to render react component at php server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, vite, server-side-rendering

## Background

- I am a WordPress developer.
- React is very effective for creating complex UIs on WordPress sites.
- I developed a small WordPress plugin that connects WordPress shortcodes with React components. This allows me to use React with WordPress.

## Problem

- I need to implement Search Engine Optimization. However, React components are rendered on the client-side. I heard that this is not good at SEO.
- How can I render React components on the server-side? I do not want to use NextJS or Remix because I only need server-side rendering and do not require a full-site SPA and Router.

## What I Found

- PHP supports the V8 JavaScript Engine.
- Vite offers support for SSR (Server-Side Rendering).

Comment: If you are using React components in the way that you target an element by id and let react replace that element with react stuff than you could let PHP put an initial content in it (so it get rendered directly when loading page) - where the content should be (in the best case) the same html React is going to render. It's not perfect in all situations but e.g. when React is only filtering a complete set of given items (masonry etc.) that search engines can read the content like they suppose to.

Answer (score 1):

React has been a simple javascript library run on top of client browser for a long time. What you want is the newly introduced React Server Components (https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project#bleeding-edge-react-frameworks) so that the UI is rendered on server-side (also known as isomorphic/SSR) as opposed to client-side.

Unfortunately, as the React docs said, it is not production-ready yet. Also, take a look at this post: https://blog.logrocket.com/react-server-components-comprehensive-guide/

> At the time of writing, the only stable way to use React Server
> Components is with the Next.js App Router.

So you have to make the trade-off: use React alongwith framework that supports SSR, or use other tools.